# Python GEKKO ODE wrong results

Tags: python, ode, gekko

I've been trying to implement the Sedaghat model for simulation of the insulin signaling pathway, as it is presented [here](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/epdf/10.1152/ajpendo.00571.2001), using python's [GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The system modeled is the one without feedback and the model's equations and constants' values can be found in Appendix A. While the first 6 diagrams of [my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HEbo.png) seem to come out fine, the rest model states (x16-x21) seem a bit problematic (fig. 6,7 of the same paper used for comparison).

I have checked the equations and constant values, tried adding lower and upper bounds to the variables and experimented with the `m.options.IMODE` and `m.options.NODES` parameters, but these didn't seem to help.

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

def insulin_pathway_CM(insulin, time_interval): 

    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.time = np.linspace(0, time_interval-1, time_interval)

    # initialization of variables 
    x1 = m.Param(value=insulin)
    x2 = m.Var(9*1e-13)
    x3 = m.Var()
    x4 = m.Var()
    x5 = m.Var()
    x6 = m.Var(1e-13)
    x7 = m.Var()
    x8 = m.Var()
    x9 = m.Var(1e-12)
    x10 = m.Var()
    x11 = m.Var(1e-13)
    x12 = m.Var()
    x13 = m.Var(0.0031)
    x14 = m.Var(0.994)
    x15 = m.Var(0.0029)
    x16 = m.Var(1)
    x17 = m.Var()
    x18 = m.Var(1)
    x19 = m.Var()
    x20 = m.Var(0.96)
    x21 = m.Var(0.04)
  
    # initialization of constants
    km1 = 0.2
    k1 = 6*1e7
    km2 = 100*km1
    k2 = k1
    km3 =  km1
    k3 = 2500
    km4 = 0.003
    k4 = km4/9
    km4a = 2.1*1e-4
    k4a = 2.1*1e-3
    km5 = 1.67*1e-18
    k5 = 10*km5    # simplification made after testing  
                   # x6 seems to be above 1e-13 for all values of interest
    k6 = 0.461
    k7 = 4.16
    km7 = (2.5/7.45)*k7
    km8 = 10
    k8 = km8 * (5/70.775) * 1e12
    km9 = (94/3.1)*1.39
    PI3K = 5*1e-15
    k9basal = (0.31/99.4)*km9
    k9 = m.Var() 
    m.Equation(k9 == (1.39 - k9basal)*(x12/PI3K) + k9basal)
    km10 = 2.77
    k10 = (3.1/2.9)*km10
    km11 = 6.9314718
    k11 = m.Var()
    m.Equation(k11 == (0.1*km11)*(x13-0.31)/2.79)
    km12 = 6.93147
    k12 = m.Var()
    m.Equation(k12 == (0.1*km12)*(x13-0.31)/2.79)
    km13 = 0.167
    k13 = (4/96)*km13
    km14 = 0.001155
    k14 = 96*km14
    
    Effect = m.Var()
    APequil = 100/11
    m.Equation(Effect == (0.2*x17 + 0.8*x19)/APequil)
    k13a = ((4/6) - (4/96))*km13*Effect
    
    SHIP = 1
    PTEN = 1
    PTP = 1
    IRp = 8.97*1e-13

    # equations
    m.Equation(x2.dt() == km1*x3 + km3*PTP*x5 - k1*x1*x2 + km4*x6 - k4*x2)
    m.Equation(x3.dt() == k1*x1*x2 - km1*x3 - k3*x3)
    m.Equation(x4.dt() == k2*x1*x5 -km2*x4 + km4a*x7 -k4a*x4)
    m.Equation(x5.dt() == k3*x3 + km2*x4 - k2*x1*x5 - km3*PTP*x5 + km4a*x8 - k4a*x5)
    m.Equation(x6.dt() == k5 - km5*x6 + k6*PTP*(x7 + x8) + k4*x2 - km4*x6)
    m.Equation(x7.dt() == k4a*x4 - km4a*x7 - k6*PTP*x7)
    m.Equation(x8.dt() == k4a*x5 - km4a*x8 - k6*PTP*x8)
    m.Equation(x9.dt() == km7*PTP*x10 - k7*x9*(x4+x5)/IRp)
    m.Equation(x10.dt() == k7*x9*(x4+x5)/IRp + km8*x12 - (km7*PTP + k8*x11)*x10)
    m.Equation(x11.dt() == km8*x12 - k8*x10*x11)
    m.Equation(x12.dt() == k8*x10*x11 - km8*x12)
    m.Equation(x13.dt() == k9*x14 + k10*x15 - (km9*PTEN + km10*SHIP)*x13)
    m.Equation(x14.dt() == km9*PTEN*x13 - k9*x14) 
    m.Equation(x15.dt() == km10*SHIP*x13 - k10*x15)
    m.Equation(x16.dt() == km11*x17 - k11*x16) 
    m.Equation(x17.dt() == k11*x16 - km11*x17)  
    m.Equation(x18.dt() == km12*x19 - k12*x18)  
    m.Equation(x19.dt() == k12*x18 - km12*x19)
    m.Equation(x20.dt() == km13*x21 - (k13 + k13a)*x20 + k14 - km14*x20)  
    m.Equation(x21.dt() == (k13 + k13a)*x20 - km13*x21) 
  
    m.options.IMODE = 7
    m.options.OTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.RTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.NODES = 3
    m.solve(disp=False)
  
    # plotting
    x45 = []
    for i in range(len(x4.value)):
        x45.append(x4[i]+x5[i])
  
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(20, 20))
    axs[0, 0].set_title('Free surface receptors (x2)')
    axs[0, 0].plot(m.time, x2)
    axs[0, 1].set_title('Once and twice bound phosphorylated receptors (x4:orange, x5:green)')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, x4, 'tab:orange')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, x5, 'tab:green')
    axs[1, 0].set_title('Surface phosphorylated receptors (x4 + x5)')
    axs[1, 0].plot(m.time, x45, 'tab:red')
    axs[1, 1].set_title('Unphosphorylated and tyrosine phosphorylated IRS-1 (x9:orange, x10:green)')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, x9, 'tab:orange')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, x10, 'tab:green')
    axs[2, 0].set_title('Activated PI 3-kinase (x12)')
    axs[2, 0].plot(m.time, x12, 'tab:orange')
    axs[2, 1].set_title('PI(3,4,5)P3 and PI(3,4,5)P2 (x13:orange, x15:green)')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, x13, 'tab:orange')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, x15, 'tab:green')
    axs[3, 0].set_title('Activated PKC-ζ (x19)')
    axs[3, 0].plot(m.time, x19, 'tab:red')
    axs[3, 1].set_title('Percentage of cell surface GLUT4 (x21)')
    axs[3, 1].plot(m.time, x21, 'tab:cyan')
    return

# input as in the paper
time_interval = 60
insulin = np.zeros(60)
insulin[:15] = 1e-7

insulin_pathway_CM(insulin, time_interval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Replace some of the states with `Intermediate` type. This gives same solution but calculates faster.

```py
    #k9 = m.Var() 
    #m.Equation(k9 == (1.39 - k9basal)*(x12/PI3K) + k9basal)
    k9 = m.Intermediate(1.39 - k9basal)*(x12/PI3K) + k9basal)
```

- Add a few small time steps at the beginning in case of early fast dynamics that are not tracking well with time step of 1. This didn't have an effect, but it is a good thing to try.

```py
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval-1, time_interval)
    m.time = np.insert(t,1,[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])
    insulin = np.insert(insulin,1,[insulin[0]]*5)
```

- Investigate any non-intuitive solutions such `x17` and `x19` as negative numbers.

Equations for `x16` to `x21` do not appear to influence other parts of the model and the only input is `k11` that is also dependent on `x13`, `x14`, and `x15`.

```py
    km11 = 6.9314718
    k11 = m.Intermediate((0.1*km11)*(x13-0.31)/2.79)
    m.Equation(x13.dt() == k9*x14 + k10*x15 - (km9*PTEN + km10*SHIP)*x13)
    m.Equation(x14.dt() == km9*PTEN*x13 - k9*x14) 
    m.Equation(x15.dt() == km10*SHIP*x13 - k10*x15)

    m.Equation(x16.dt() == km11*x17 - k11*x16) 
    m.Equation(x17.dt() == k11*x16 - km11*x17)  
    m.Equation(x18.dt() == km12*x19 - k12*x18)  
    m.Equation(x19.dt() == k12*x18 - km12*x19)
    m.Equation(x20.dt() == km13*x21 - (k13 + k13a)*x20 + k14 - km14*x20)  
    m.Equation(x21.dt() == (k13 + k13a)*x20 - km13*x21)
```

There may be a model error in those equations, possibly even in the original paper (it sometimes happens). Focusing on pairs `x16` and `x17`, it appears that `x17` is just the change in `x16`. This is similar for `x18` and `x19`. At first glance, I couldn't see any obvious differences in the equations between the Python source code and the paper.

[image: Results x16-x21]

[image: Paper results]

Here is the complete script with some changes with Intermediates, 2 plots added, and the additional time points at the beginning.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

def insulin_pathway_CM(insulin, time_interval): 

    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval-1, time_interval)
    m.time = np.insert(t,1,[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])
    print(m.time)
    insulin = np.insert(insulin,1,[insulin[0]]*5)

    # initialization of variables 
    x1 = m.Param(value=insulin)
    x2 = m.Var(9*1e-13)
    x3 = m.Var()
    x4 = m.Var()
    x5 = m.Var()
    x6 = m.Var(1e-13)
    x7 = m.Var()
    x8 = m.Var()
    x9 = m.Var(1e-12)
    x10 = m.Var()
    x11 = m.Var(1e-13)
    x12 = m.Var()
    x13 = m.Var(0.0031)
    x14 = m.Var(0.994)
    x15 = m.Var(0.0029)
    x16 = m.Var(1)
    x17 = m.Var()
    x18 = m.Var(1)
    x19 = m.Var()
    x20 = m.Var(0.96)
    x21 = m.Var(0.04)
  
    # initialization of constants
    km1 = 0.2
    k1 = 6*1e7
    km2 = 100*km1
    k2 = k1
    km3 =  km1
    k3 = 2500
    km4 = 0.003
    k4 = km4/9
    km4a = 2.1*1e-4
    k4a = 2.1*1e-3
    km5 = 1.67*1e-18
    k5 = 10*km5    # simplification made after testing  
                   # x6 seems to be above 1e-13 for all values of interest
    k6 = 0.461
    k7 = 4.16
    km7 = (2.5/7.45)*k7
    km8 = 10
    k8 = km8 * (5/70.775) * 1e12
    km9 = (94/3.1)*1.39
    PI3K = 5*1e-15
    k9basal = (0.31/99.4)*km9
    k9 = m.Intermediate((1.39 - k9basal)*(x12/PI3K) + k9basal)
    km10 = 2.77
    k10 = (3.1/2.9)*km10
    km11 = 6.9314718
    k11 = m.Intermediate((0.1*km11)*(x13-0.31)/2.79)
    km12 = 6.93147
    k12 = m.Intermediate((0.1*km12)*(x13-0.31)/2.79)
    km13 = 0.167
    k13 = (4/96)*km13
    km14 = 0.001155
    k14 = 96*km14
    
    APequil = 100/11
    Effect = m.Intermediate((0.2*x17 + 0.8*x19)/APequil)
    k13a = ((4/6) - (4/96))*km13*Effect
    
    SHIP = 1
    PTEN = 1
    PTP = 1
    IRp = 8.97*1e-13

    # equations
    m.Equation(x2.dt() == km1*x3 + km3*PTP*x5 - k1*x1*x2 + km4*x6 - k4*x2)
    m.Equation(x3.dt() == k1*x1*x2 - km1*x3 - k3*x3)
    m.Equation(x4.dt() == k2*x1*x5 -km2*x4 + km4a*x7 -k4a*x4)
    m.Equation(x5.dt() == k3*x3 + km2*x4 - k2*x1*x5 - km3*PTP*x5 + km4a*x8 - k4a*x5)
    m.Equation(x6.dt() == k5 - km5*x6 + k6*PTP*(x7 + x8) + k4*x2 - km4*x6)
    m.Equation(x7.dt() == k4a*x4 - km4a*x7 - k6*PTP*x7)
    m.Equation(x8.dt() == k4a*x5 - km4a*x8 - k6*PTP*x8)
    m.Equation(x9.dt() == km7*PTP*x10 - k7*x9*(x4+x5)/IRp)
    m.Equation(x10.dt() == k7*x9*(x4+x5)/IRp + km8*x12 - (km7*PTP + k8*x11)*x10)
    m.Equation(x11.dt() == km8*x12 - k8*x10*x11)
    m.Equation(x12.dt() == k8*x10*x11 - km8*x12)
    m.Equation(x13.dt() == k9*x14 + k10*x15 - (km9*PTEN + km10*SHIP)*x13)
    m.Equation(x14.dt() == km9*PTEN*x13 - k9*x14) 
    m.Equation(x15.dt() == km10*SHIP*x13 - k10*x15)
    m.Equation(x16.dt() == km11*x17 - k11*x16) 
    m.Equation(x17.dt() == k11*x16 - km11*x17)  
    m.Equation(x18.dt() == km12*x19 - k12*x18)  
    m.Equation(x19.dt() == k12*x18 - km12*x19)
    m.Equation(x20.dt() == km13*x21 - (k13 + k13a)*x20 + k14 - km14*x20)  
    m.Equation(x21.dt() == (k13 + k13a)*x20 - km13*x21) 
  
    m.options.IMODE = 7
    m.options.OTOL  = 1e-10
    m.options.RTOL  = 1e-10
    m.options.NODES = 3
    m.solve(disp=False)
  
    # plotting
    x45 = []
    for i in range(len(x4.value)):
        x45.append(x4[i]+x5[i])
  
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(20, 20))
    axs[0, 0].set_title('Free surface receptors (x2)')
    axs[0, 0].plot(m.time, x2)
    axs[0, 1].set_title('Once and twice bound phosphorylated receptors (x4:orange, x5:green)')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, x4, 'tab:orange')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, x5, 'tab:green')
    axs[1, 0].set_title('Surface phosphorylated receptors (x4 + x5)')
    axs[1, 0].plot(m.time, x45, 'tab:red')
    axs[1, 1].set_title('Unphosphorylated and tyrosine phosphorylated IRS-1 (x9:orange, x10:green)')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, x9, 'tab:orange')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, x10, 'tab:green')
    axs[2, 0].set_title('Activated PI 3-kinase (x12)')
    axs[2, 0].plot(m.time, x12, 'tab:orange')
    axs[2, 1].set_title('PI(3,4,5)P3 and PI(3,4,5)P2 (x13:orange, x15:green)')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, x13, 'tab:orange')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, x15, 'tab:green')
    axs[3, 0].set_title('Activated PKC-ζ (x19)')
    axs[3, 0].plot(m.time, x19, 'tab:red')
    axs[3, 1].set_title('Percentage of cell surface GLUT4 (x21)')
    axs[3, 1].plot(m.time, x21, 'tab:cyan')
    
    plt.figure()
    for ni in range(16,22):
        nx = 'x'+str(ni); x = eval(nx)
        plt.subplot(3,2,ni-15)
        plt.plot(m.time,x.value,label=nx); plt.legend()

    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(m.time,k11.value,label='k11')
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(m.time,x13.value,label='x13')

    return

# input as in the paper
time_interval = 60
insulin = np.zeros(60)
insulin[:15] = 1e-7

insulin_pathway_CM(insulin, time_interval)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! The differences in `x19` and `x21` could also be due to the simplification made when initializing `k5`, whose value depends on the `x6+x7+x8` sum using an `if` condition in the original paper (App. A). However, I wasn't sure about how that could be implemented (maybe this could be addressed in a new question post). I made this simplification because `x6+x7+x8>1e-13` seemed to be always true, after plotting `x6` to `x8` for some cases. Since the first diagrams came out right the simplification was considered valid, but I could be very wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Check out the if3 function in gekko for conditionals. If you can’t get it, feel free to create a new question.